# Git Submodule/Subtree specific folders/projects

Tags: git, git-submodules, git-subtree, subtree

So my issue is I have 2 solutions and 1 relies on certain projects from the other so I have:

Solution 1 (repository)

- project 1
- project 2
- project 3
- project 4

Solution 2 (repository)

- project 1
- project 3
- project 5

So see the overlap that solution 1 and 2 share projects 1 and 3, in the cvs world we accomplished this easily but I haven't found how to do this in git.

I have see submodule and subtree but from my understanding this share at a repository level and do not allow for specific projects/folders to be shared within the repository.

The Solutions we have are actually much larger than described above (solution 1 has 44 projects). the idea we are floating around but we don't really like is to create a separate repository for each project that needs to be shared but this would mean 17 or so extra repositories, there has to be an easier way no?

Thank you.

Comment: You should read up more on Git submodules.  I think this is probably what you want, it's not all that hard to implement, and there is already lots of documentation out there on the topic.

Comment: If subtrees and submodules are inconvenient solutions, could you update the question to articulate what the drawbacks are from your point of view ?